# sql query displaying an average quantity

Tags: sql, join, average

So i have these two tables with the following columns:

1. Reps:

Rep ID
Rep name

2. Transactions:

Transaction ID
Price
RepID

I want to get all reps that had transactions in a total of an average number (200).

Is it:

```
 SELECT * from Reps
 INNER JOIN Transactions
 ON Reps.Rep ID = Transactions.RepId
 WHERE Transactions.Price>(SELECT AVG(200) FROM Transactions);
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to get Reps having an average `Price` value that is over `200`:

```
SELECT RepID 
FROM Reps
INNER JOIN Transactions
ON Reps.RepID = Transactions.RepId
GROUP BY RepID
HAVING AVG(Price) > 200
```

Comment: No, sorry - i need average prices **over** 200,

Comment: @OBZ: Then change this line - `HAVING AVG(Price) = 200` to this - `HAVING AVG(Price) > 200`

Answer (score 0):

```
  select r.repid 
    from reps r,
(select avg(price),repid from transactions group by repid having avg(price)>200) t 
    where r.repid=t.repid
```